# I cannot use vi even after installing vim in RedHat

Tags: bash, vim, redhat, vi

I'm not able to open file using vi command. I'm able to open with vim, but I'm not able to open with vi. This happened after I tried to enable syntax lighting(the coloring thing in terminal). I can open files with `vim` but not able to open with vi.

```
[root@123-dev-lnx ~]# vi index.html
bash: index.html: command not found...
[root@123-dev-lnx ~]# vim index.html
[root@123-dev-lnx ~]#
```

Comment: you probably have an alias on vi; type `alias | grep vi` andcheck it

Comment: @OznOg I get this 
`alias vi=''`  But I don't have this in my .bashrc

Comment: check what happens, when you `unalias vi`

Comment: @UtLox That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking your aliases with

```
 alias | grep vi
```

you saw

```
alias vi=''
```

which basically means that the `vi` command itself is replaced by nothing, leading the command:

```
$ vi index.html
```

to become

```
$ index.html
```

which tells the shell to launch a program named `index.html` which doe not exists.

as suggested in cmments,

```
unalias vi
```

allowed to remove the alias and have the vi being called.

That said, unless you have explicitly typed the bad alias in your console, it may be somewhere in your configuration files and will probably keep bothering you in the future...